# Enterprise Architect, Package and DiagramLinks creation from c# script

Tags: c#, package

I have minors Troubles after trying to generate a package and some diagram links with a c# script .

1) My first issue is about the package stereotype, I used the following commands, but the package sterotype won't change :

```
EA.Package NewPackage = thePackageOutput.Packages.AddNew("APP_Name", "");
NewPackage.StereotypeEx = "SWAppTest";
NewPackage.Update();
```

My package is created but the Stereotype SWAppTest is not.

2) My second Point is about a specific type of connector, i wanted to link some elements with connectors type of "Aggregation". They are black arrows with a **BLACK** diamond arrow head. I can create them in E.A. by using the "Aggregation to Whole" command. I have used these commands in my c# script :

```
EA.Connector NewConnector = ElementAPPLICATION.Connectors.AddNew("", "Aggregation");
NewConnector.SupplierID = NewElement.ElementID;
NewConnector.Update();
```

But I ended up with another type of arrow, with a WHITE diamond arrow head. But when clicking on it, they do have the type "Aggregation". How do I make the difference between them ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

In case other people have the same problem in the future, I've fixed the first issue by updating twice and refreshing.

```
EA.Package NewPackage = thePackageOutput.Packages.AddNew(APP_Name, "AA");
thePackageOutput.Packages.Refresh();
NewPackage.Update();
NewPackage.Element.Stereotype = "SWAppTest";
NewPackage.Update();
```